# How do I make coffee with Ubuntu?

Tags: wireless, software-recommendation, home-automation

I want to make fresh coffee with Ubuntu, using open/free software, a coffee machine and a wireless connection. What software can I use that is already available, and what hardware do I need to connect/operate a coffee machine at distance using that software?

By coffee machine, at this point, I mean a simple water boiler.

More specifically all that would be needed is a device that could turn on the power of a simple coffee maker, how would I go about controlling something like this from Ubuntu?

Comment: You could take a look at Arduino (http://www.arduino.cc) ... as an example: http://makezine.com/2014/03/28/arduino-controlled-tec-coolingheating-system-for-beer-fermentation/

Comment: I would like to see something creative here using Ubuntu Snappy, I'm sure something could be done with that to make a Ubuntu controlled coffee maker.

Comment: Or with Raspberry Pi (https://www.raspberrypi.org/), IMO it would make the networking part a lot easier

Comment: Well, if someone finds a way of doing this, then I will definitely give it a go! It could be like the Teasmade reinvented... ;)

Comment: I'd say an arduino could work...

Comment: Use Java. Naturally.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should be enough:

Software: `sudo apt-get install bottlerocket` via [aboutdebian](http://www.aboutdebian.com/x10.htm) which is also available in Ubuntu 15.04.

Hardware: [cm19a usb unit](http://www.x10.com/x10-home-automation/interfaces/cm19a.html) (or serial unit) and a [kr19a](http://www.x10.com/packaged-deals/home-automation/kitwirelesskr19a.html) from x10.com gives you a usb controller, a wireless receiver, keychain transmitter and a lamp unit for the coffee pot. You might want to compare against [amazon](http://www.amazon.com/s/?field-brandtextbin=X10&node=228013) for pricing.

Comment: The stuff from x10.com is pretty cheap and they often have sales.  Look for one of the bundle sales that includes the kr19a as you can usually get a bunch of pieces for the same price as a single one, usually through their e-mail list.  This project looks like a fun and cheap way of integrating ubuntu and home automation devices.

Comment: I just found a bunch of x10 stuff at goodwill for a few dollars a piece :)